# Ise simulation VHDL

Tags: embedded, hardware, vhdl

I would like to ask the following. I am working on an FPGA Tetris design. My code language is VHDL in ISE Environment in windows 7.

While I progress my work I ofter check my work with isim simulation. As the design is getting big isim stops working and closes. Basically the module causing this crash is a big fsm. When I comment some states of the fsm ISIM is working fine again.

It doesn't matter which states I will comment. I can check the fsm working in parts. But I can not test it as a whole. Is it possible that this is not code error and it is just ISIM?

Thanks

Comment: It's likely there is some problem with your code, which is upsetting ISIM, but the ISIM crashes make it harder to diagnose. Cross-check with another simulator, for example http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghdl-updates/

Comment: The thing is that  I check my code until let's say point x at which I have 150 sates and everything works fine. Then I write 20 more states and I get this error. Than I comment some of the 150 states that I know they actually working and the 20 states that at first caused isim to crash are also working. I read somewhere that in big designs isim is unstable. But I need to know for sure if it is isim problem or my code! I would also say my code, but it is strange that the states that are creating the problem are working just fine when the design gets smaller!

Comment: If your state machine has 150+ states, that might give the synthesis tools some trouble.  You might consider how you can remove about 130 of those states.

Comment: @Russell I have 154 states. But I need them all and I guess I will need another 100 states. Can I use more fsm's maybe? Can I use one fsm per 30 states?

Comment: I really would advise against more FSMs. It gets too confusing. Can you do more things in different processes..?

Comment: @Russell I am not sure. This fsm is the game control module. I don't know how can I split the game control in more than one processes! Can I split the control in many processes and get the same result!?

Comment: What does XST say to your code? XST and iSim use different parsers so maybe you get a more detailed report. Besides of GHDL there is also the possibility to user the new Vivado simulator xSim. Can you simulate the standalone FSM (150+ states)? You can split up your game logic by extracting functions of a game to separate FSMs and implement a new main_FSM to control each function_FSM -> think of a C programm where main_FSM calls a function and gets a return value.

Comment: @Paebbels Yes with xsim in vivado  I can simulate with no problem. Thanks. 
Let me ask you though, can I use the vivado instead of ISE to make my design?
And one more thing, in isim I can see the memory I have in my deisgn, can I do the same with xsim? Because I can not find it?
Thanks

Comment: It would be interesting to see your FSM. Can you post (a link to) the code?

Comment: Yes of course, here it is
http://www.snipplr.com/view/82401/myfsm/

Comment: @DimitriC hmmm xSim works fine ... I hoped that you got a more detailed error :) Vivado supports only new FPGAs (Series-7 and Ultra-Scale). However, you can use xSim for old devices. xSim is a new version of iSim, so all features should be present. In contrast the new embedded ChipScope (don't know the correct name ... Debug Probes?) has less features then the old ChipScope.

Comment: @DimitriC I can't open the snippet URL => *The snippet you're looking for has either been deleted by its owner or it never existed to begin with.*

Comment: http://www.snipplr.com/view/82403/gamecontroller/

Can you now @Paebbels

Comment: So I read your snippet. See my answer below for some hints and faults => not all source lines are synthesizable, but iSim should parse it .... Is this snippet a crashing one?

Answer (score 0):

**How to split a complex FSM into parts?**
Here are some example lines to illustrate a simple call/return handshaking protocol between a main FSM and two function FSMs

```
process(Clock)
begin
    if (Reset = '1') then
        MainFSM_State       <= ST_IDLE;
        Func1FSM_State  <= ST_IDLE;
        Func2FSM_State  <= ST_IDLE;
    else
        MainFSM_State       <= MainFSM_NextState;
        Func1FSM_State  <= Func1FSM_NextState;
        Func2FSM_State  <= Func2FSM_NextState;
    end if;
end process;

process(MainFSM_State, Input, ...,
                Func1FSM_Output, Func1FSM_Return,
                Func2FSM_Output, Func2FSM_Return)
begin
    Func1FSM_Call           <= '0';
    Func2FSM_Call           <= '0';

    MainFSM_Output      <= x"00";

    case MainFSM_State is
        when ST_IDLE =>
            if (Input = '1') then
                Func1FSM_Call               <= '1';
                MainFSM_NextState       <= ST_FUNC1_EXECUTING;
            end if;

        when ST_FUNC1_EXECUTING =>
            MainFSM_Output              <= Func1FSM_Output;

            if (Func1FSM_Return = '1') then
                Func2FSM_Call               <= '1';
            end if;

       ....
    end case;
end process;
```

## Some general hints for your design (based on the code snippet)

Using big FSMs is also very fault-prone. So one goal of writing big FSMs should be readability, so you can find errors more easily.

- Don't use std_logic_arith, std_logic_unsigned while numeric_std is used. Use only numeric_std, that's adequate.
- `wait until` is not a synthesizeable statement. Use:

  ```
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    ...
  end if;
  ```
- Are your external inputs like *reset_switch* synchronized and debounced? A signal name like reset_switch implies that this signal is raw ;)
- You can improve the readability of `if..elsif..else..end if;` statements by using case statements (see line 230)
- You use masses of binary assignments like `t_left_most <= "010111"; --23`. Maybe it's better to declare *t_left_most* with another type (e.g. a constrained natural), so you can use integer literals in your FSM. For exporting these signals to other modules the signal is converted back to std_logic_vector. -> improved readability
- Some times it's good to introduce constants e.g.

  ```
  constant C_TOP_MOST : NATURAL := 0;
  ```
- I would advice you to extract your counter `memReadAddress` from your FSM. Big FSMs should only generate flow-control signals, FSMs should not contain any data-flow logic (counters, multiplexers, ...). So extract the counter to a separate process and add control signals to your big FSM.

  ```
  when T_block_1 =>
    ReadAddressCounter_en  <= '1';
  ```

  Personally, I use prefixes like _rst, _en, _us, _inc, _dec for the counter control signals. _us stands for unsigned, because the my counters are unsigned counters and the value is converted to std_logic if needed.

  Counter example with FSM 'remote control' signals:

  ```
  process(Clock)
  begin
    if rising_edge(Clock) then
      if ((Reset or MemAddressCounter_rst) = '1') then
        MemAddressCounter_us      <= (others => '0');
      else
        if (MemAddressCounter_load = '1') then
          MemAddressCounter_us    <= to_unsigned(5, MemAddressCounter_us'length);
        elsif (MemAddressCounter_inc = '1') then
          MemAddressCounter_us    <= MemAddressCounter_us + 1;
        end if;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

  MemAddress  <= std_logic_vector(MemAddressCounter_us);
  ```
- line 286 should not be synthesizable (I think Xilinx XST is not smart enough and if so, it's not predictable what XST would produce ...)

  ```
  dataIn<=dataOut(39 downto conv_integer(T_left_most+1))&T_square&T_square&T_square&dataOut(conv_integer(T_right_most-1) downto 0);
  ```

So how can you fix the last point in the list of my hints?

1. simple way: use a 40:1 multiplexer
2. more advanced way: try to use mask and bit-shift operations
3. use another data structure, which is more suitable for hardware :)

If you want a more detailed discussion on this points, please leave a comment and I will try to extend my answer.

## Extended answer - bit operation solution

So lets summarize line 286:

```
dataIn <= dataOut(39 downto conv_integer(T_left_most+1)) &
          T_square & T_square & T_square &
          dataOut(conv_integer(T_right_most-1) downto 0);
```

Your result consists of 3 parts:

- dataout sliced from MSB downto dynamic marker
- 3 bits
- dataout sliced from dynamic marker downto 0

This bit insertion can also be done by a bitwise set/clear operation:

- set: `result <= input or set_mask;`
- clear: `result <= input and not clear_mask;`

This can be combined to a bit override operation:

- override: `result <= (input and not override_mask) or override_value;`
- secure override `result <= (input and not override_mask) or (override_value and override_mask);`

The latter must be used if you can not assume that override_value has only bits set within the range of override_mask.

The next step is to move T_square to the right position. Shifting bits in a fast way can be done by a barrel-shifter or a multiplier (DSP block). Because your vector has 40 bits, a barrel-shifter is faster then a DSP block.

A barrel shifter of 64 bits has a 6 bit shift_value input. Each bit of the input specifies if the value should be shifted by a power of two.

```
entity arith_BarrelShifter is
  generic (
    BITS            : POSITIVE      := 32
  );
  port (
    Input           : in    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(BITS - 1 downto 0);
    ShiftAmount     : in    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(log2ceilnz(BITS) - 1 downto 0);
    Output          : out   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(BITS - 1 downto 0)
  );
end;

architecture rtl of arith_BarrelShifter is
  constant STAGES       : POSITIVE      := log2ceilnz(BITS);

  subtype   T_INTERMEDIATE_RESULT is STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(BITS - 1 downto 0);
  type  T_INTERMEDIATE_VECTOR is array (NATURAL range <>) of T_INTERMEDIATE_RESULT;

  signal IntermediateResults    : T_INTERMEDIATE_VECTOR(STAGES downto 0);

begin
  IntermediateResults(0)    <= Input;
  Output                    <= IntermediateResults(STAGES);

  for i in 0 to STAGES - 1 generate
    process(IntermediateResults(i), ShiftRotate, LeftRight, ArithmeticLogic)
    begin
      if (ShiftAmount(i) = '0') then
        IntermediateResults(i + 1) <= IntermediateResults(i);
      else
        IntermediateResults(i + 1) <= IntermediateResults(i)((BITS - i**2 - 1) downto 0) & ((i**2 - 1) downto 0 => '0');                                                        -- SLA, SLL
      end if;
    end process;
  end generate;
end;
```

So now we can combine all steps:

```
override_value <= (39 downto 3 => '0') & (2 downto 0 => T_square);
override_mask  <= (39 downto 3 => '0') & (2 downto 0 => '1');

shift_value : entity PoC.arith_BarrelShifter
  generic map (
    BITS        => 40
  )
  port map (
    Input       => override_value,
    ShiftAmount => T_left_most,
    Output      => shifted_value
  );

shift_mask : entity PoC.arith_BarrelShifter
  generic map (
    BITS        => 40
  )
  port map (
    Input       => override_mask,
    ShiftAmount => T_left_most,
    Output      => shifted_mask
  );

--           clear bits from source   / set bits from value
dataIn <= (dataOut and not shifted_mask) or shifted_value;
```

I hope I made no mistakes :)

Comment: first of all thanks a lot for the time you spent. I would like to ask you to elaborate on the last point, where you say I can use a mask and bit-shift operations, I tries this at some point and I met some trouble so I abandoned the idea, can you walk me through this please.>

And secondly,  considering constant C_TOP_MOST : NATURAL := 0, can I add or subtract number from c_top_most and how?

Comment: @DimitriC I extended my answer with a bit operation solution as requested. The function log2ceilnz calculates the twos logarithm.

Comment: Once more thank you very much. I After your advises I changed a lot my code and I have managed the same functionality with 21 states. (154 initially). Now synthesize problems has began. When I synthesize my code, it hangs on hdl elaboration forever, and it consumes all the ram available no matter how much. I even tried to synthesize it in a computer with 16 gb of ram and it consumes 15.2 gm of ram!

Comment: How many barrel shifters are in your design? Can you reduce the 40 bits to lets say 20?